# R: categorize obtain a new table

Tags: r

[image]

I have such a table with 3 columns rs10330, rs18976 and rs749. I want to obtain the last column `identifiedID` which row have one of AG or GG, GT or TT, AT or TT in each column, the `identifiedID` will be 1, and which have two the `identifiedID` will be 2. As for row 1 ,there is no AG or GG, GT or TT, AT or TT for 3 column,therefore, the `identifiedID` is 0.

In order to obtain `identifiedID`, what is the code?

Data:

```
datmp <- data.frame(rs10330=c('AA','AG','GG','AG','AA'), 
                    rs18976=c('GG','GT','GT','GG','GG'), 
                    rs7498=c( 'AA','AT','TT','AT','TT')) 
identifiedID <- c(0,3,3,2,1) 
datmp2 <- data.frame(datmp, identifiedID)
```

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: the code for the table:datmp <- data.frame(rs10330=c('AA','AG','GG','AG','AA'),
                    rs18976=c('GG','GT','GT','GG','GG'),
                    rs7498=c( 'AA','AT','TT','AT','TT'))
identifiedID <- c(0,3,3,2,1)
datmp2 <- data.frame(datmp,identifiedID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very verbose solution would be

```r
datmp %>%
    mutate(identifiedID = rs10330 %in% c("AG", "GG") + 
               rs18976 %in% c("GT", "TT") + 
                    rs7498 %in% c("AT", "TT"))
#  rs10330 rs18976 rs7498 identifiedID
#1      AA      GG     AA            0
#2      AG      GT     AT            3
#3      GG      GT     TT            3
#4      AG      GG     AT            2
#5      AA      GG     TT            1
```